# JQuery UI Autocomplete set default VALUE using ID (value) instead of Label

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

i've created a JQuery UI Autocomplete in which the source is an array of label-value pairs.
i need to set the default selected item. i found a way to do that using the desired label,
but how can i do that if i have the **VALUE** instead of the **LABEL**?

code for setting default value using label string :

```
$("myAutoCom").autocomplete("search", "someLabel");
var menu = $("myAutoCom").autocomplete("widget");
$(menu[0].children[0]).click();
```

i have the value,not the label. how can i set selected item depending on value?
thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to do what you wan't. But there might be workaround: if you have object containing all the values, you can set the default autocomplete widget value, by passing label accessed by it's value from all values object, something like this: $("myAutoCom").val(allvaluesobject[label_value_key]);

Comment: Thank u so much! i did as you said. The source of my autocomplete is a two-dimensional array of labels and values,that array is kept in a global variable, so i just searched that array for corresponding  label and used it as a default value for my autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the source of my autocomplete is an array that contains all label-value pairs, and since i keep that array in a global variable, i just did the following:

searched THAT array for the given value and returned the corresponding label, then used that label to initialize the autocomplete using the code mentioned in the question.

thanks to @sepikas-antanas